# How to profile python 3.5 code line by line in jupyter notebook 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, profiling, jupyter-notebook

How to find out execution time taken by each line of python code.

line_profiler works with ipython but doesnt work with jupyter notebook. I tried adding @profile to my function, it gives error saying name 'profile' is not defined. 
There is one way to do it by time.time() , but i was wondering if there is any inbuilt profiling function which can profile each line of my function and show me the execution time.

```
def prof_function():
    x=10*20
    y=10+x
    return (y)
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use `line_profiler` in jupyter notebook.

1. Install it: `pip install line_profiler`
2. Within your jupyter notebook, call: `%load_ext line_profiler`
3. Define your function `prof_function` as in your example.
4. Finally, profile as follows: `%lprun -f prof_function prof_function()`

Which will provide the output:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 3e-06 s
File: <ipython-input-22-41854af628da>
Function: prof_function at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def prof_function():
     2         1          1.0      1.0     33.3      x=10*20
     3         1          1.0      1.0     33.3      y=10+x
     4         1          1.0      1.0     33.3      return (y)
```

---

Note that you can profile *any* function in the call hierarchy, not just the top one. If the function you want to profile isn't in the notebook, you must import it. Unfortunately you can only profile functions which are run from source code, not from libraries you've installed (unless they were installed from source).

Example:

```
 import numpy as np

 def sub_function():
     a = np.random.random((3, 4))
     x = 10 * a
     return x

 def prof_function():
     y = sub_function()
     z = 10 + y
     return z
```

Output of `%lprun -f prof_function prof_function()`:

```
 Timer unit: 1e-09 s

 Total time: 3.2e-05 s
 File: /var/folders/hh/f20wzr451rd3m04552cf7n4r0000gp/T/ipykernel_51803/3816028199.py
 Function: prof_function at line 6

 Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
 ==============================================================
      6                                           def prof_function():
      7         1      29000.0  29000.0     90.6      y = sub_function()
      8         1       3000.0   3000.0      9.4      z = 10 + y
      9         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      return z
```

Output of `%lprun -f sub_function prof_function()`:

```
 Timer unit: 1e-09 s

 Total time: 2.7e-05 s
 File: /var/folders/hh/f20wzr451rd3m04552cf7n4r0000gp/T/ipykernel_51803/572113936.py
 Function: sub_function at line 1

 Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
 ==============================================================
      1                                           def sub_function():
      2         1      13000.0  13000.0     48.1      a = np.random.random((3, 4))
      3         1      14000.0  14000.0     51.9      x = 10 * a
      4         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      return x
```

More detail in [this nice blog post](http://mortada.net/easily-profile-python-code-in-jupyter.html).

Comment: It works even if you interrupt the execution while running !

Comment: @TomasG. I followed the exact same steps but it showed that the requirement is already satisfied i.e. already installed. But didn't show the Line Contents saying "Are you sure you are running this program from the same directory that you ran the profiler from?"
Continuing without the function's contents.   What could be the reason?

Comment: I would redo the steps in a new isolated Python environment, using whatever environment manager you like (conda, venv, ...).

Comment: Can confirm what happened to Tomas G.

Answer (score 24):

To get the execution time for each line and get a nice colour coded heatmap, I use this nice ipython magic.... https://github.com/csurfer/pyheatmagic

[image]

Installation:

> pip install py-heat-magic

To profile every single line in notebook:

- duplicate your notebook.
- Merge all cells (highlight all and shift-m)
- Create a new cell at the top
- enter

`%load_ext heat`

At the top of your 2nd cell enter this at the 1st line:

```
%%heat
```

You may have issues if you have more than 2000 lines of code.

Comment: Looks great, but be aware of this issue: https://github.com/csurfer/pyheatmagic/issues/6

Comment: @fjsj I think it does not want any values from previous cells, would be nice if it worked, but I pasted my relevant code into a .py file and used the basic https://github.com/csurfer/pyheat instead.

Comment: Is there something similar to this but for a Jupyter Notebook running an `R` kernel? Found this SO post after asking my question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172281/is-it-possible-to-benchmark-an-entire-jupyterlab-notebook

Comment: This is *almost* useless; It can't access ***any*** context outside the current cell, which means its essentially limited to analyzing self-contained python scripts. It won't even see global configuration variables or numpy/pylab/matplotlib bindings unless you re-import them! In a data science development context, you need to be able to test short bits of code, and it is absurd to re-instate an entire notebook's context in a single cell (and may take several minutes, wasting development time and breaking attention). I say *almost* because re-initializing everything is better than nothing.

Comment: Edit: I've tested this, and it seems to still have some bugs. It reports that my code spends 100% of its time in a trivial line which I can verify takes no more than 0.01% of the execution time. 0/10 do not recommend as of 02/2023.

Answer (score 15):

Just a summary of @S.A.'s answer

```py
!pip install line_profiler
%load_ext line_profiler

def func():
    print('hi')

%lprun -f func func()
```

Answer (score 3):

Install line profiler

`conda install line_profiler`

More info on http://mortada.net/easily-profile-python-code-in-jupyter.html