# Is it possible to benchmark an entire JupyterLab Notebook?

Tags: r, benchmarking, jupyter-lab

I'm not sure if this is a CV question or SO, so I apologize if it falls within the CV domain.

---

**Problem**

I know it's possible to `microbenchmark` specific chunks of R code, but is there any benchmark-ing tool for an entire Jupyter Notebook? I could just run the entire notebook and time it manually, but I'd like more statistics and precision on the timing for which the `microbenchmark` package provides (I'm trying to make a case for automation of data analyses and visualizations).

The other dilemma (an overall issue with notebooks) is that my notebook is divided into many individual cells, so the option of benchmark-ing in the Jupyter environment might be inefficient (forcing me to export all code and then running a `microbenchmark` on it say in R Studio).

---

**Desired Solution**

An efficient way to benchmark an entire, multi-celled JupyterLab Notebook.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know much about Jupyter Notebooks. I would say if there is a command to run all code in a Notebook from `R` (or another language) then benchmark this command. If there isn't, it's not possible. Maybe that's already obvious but you don't mention it. For RMarkdown it would be simply: `microbenchmark(rmarkdown::render("notbook.Rmd"))`.