# How to create X_train and y_train from very large datasets?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'm trying to work the RSNA Screening Mammography Breast Cancer Detection competition on Kaggle. There is a lot of image data. The data is setup where there are 11,000 folders, each with 4 images in them. Below is the loop I'm using to create X_train and y_train:

```
def read_xray(file_path, img_size=None):
    dicom = pydicom.read_file(file_path)
    img = dicom.pixel_array

    if dicom.PhotometricInterpretation == "MONOCHROME1":
        img = np.max(img) - img

    if img_size:
        img = cv2.resize(img, img_size)

    # Add channel dim at First
    img = img[np.newaxis]

    # Converting img to float32
    img = img / np.max(img)
    img = img.astype("float32")

    return img


X_train = []
y_train = []
def create_train_datasets(img_path, df):
    for folder in tqdm(os.listdir(img_path)):
        folder_path = os.path.join(img_path, folder)
        for img in os.listdir(folder_path):
            im_path = os.path.join(folder_path, img)
            image = read_xray(im_path, img_size=(512, 512))
            X_train.append(image)
            label = df.loc[df['patient_id'] == 'folder', 'cancer']
            y_train.append(label)
```

But this is very slow and would take hours to iterate through the dataset. Eventually I will convert X_train and y_train into Pytorch Tensors and create a Dataloader. Is there any way to make this faster? Or is there a better way of creating the training dataset I will use?

I have looked through some of the other notebooks for this competition on Kaggle, but I'm looking for a more simple approach to creating the training dataset.

Comment: `df.loc[df['patient_id'] == 'folder', 'cancer']` This line looks a little suspicious - it does a full search of the dataframe to identify the one label you're looking for. It can be faster to do `df = df.set_index('patient_id')` outside the loop, then `df.loc[folder, 'cancer']` to look up each label. But I don't know if that matters - you're also loading a lot of image data, and that may dominate the total time taken.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a profile of how much time is being spent in each line. Could you profile your code using these instructions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734297/how-to-profile-python-3-5-code-line-by-line-in-jupyter-notebook-5

Comment: Do you solved this stack mr @conweezy ?